# Pyserial COM Port issue

Tags: python, pyserial

I am using [Pyserial 2.6](https://learn.adafruit.com/arduino-lesson-17-email-sending-movement-detector/installing-python-and-pyserial) on Windows 7, and I am trying to connect to a [Tiva C Series Launchpad](https://www.ti.com/ww/en/launchpad/launchpads-connected-ek-tm4c123gxl.html). It is listed as COM5 under device manager, and I've successfully downloaded and installed all the necessary drivers. I program the board using TI's CCS, and everything connects and works fine.

But, for some reason, when I actually try to access it using pyserial, it is not recognized. I run:

```
python -m serial.tools.list_ports
```

I get:

```
COM1
COM3
COM4
3 ports found
```

But I do not find COM5... which is where my Tiva is. I have no idea what's going on. I'm not sure what's going on... is there something I am doing wrong? I linked the installation instructions I followed for installing Pyserial. Is there something else that needs to be done..?

Thank you very much

Comment: Which ports are listed in device manager? What does the command line tell you about [available COM ports](https://superuser.com/questions/835848/how-to-view-serial-com-ports-but-not-through-device-manager)? What does `serial.tools.list_ports.comports()` give you as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29813811/3991125)

Answer (score 2):

Well this can be anything. The following code works for me:

```
def _scan_com_ports(self):
    """
    Scan for available COM ports. return a list of tuples (num, name)
    """
    available = []
    for i in range(10):
        try:
            s = serial.Serial(i)  # if not existing an exception occured
            available.append((i, s.portstr))
            s.close()  # explicit close 'cause of delayed GC in java
            if debug:
                print("Com:", i + 1)
        except serial.SerialException:
            if debug:
                print("Not to open", i)
            # needed to cope with comp witch are not to open
            pass
    return available
```

Probably the search gives up to early.

Comment: Interesting... when I run this code, nothing happens. Nothing is outputted to the screen... interesting..

Comment: @JohnLexus have you set `debug`? Have you built the invoking test code to print the return value?